# JSON API in PHP

Tags: php, html, json

My android developer require JSON response like below.

```
[
{   "StudentId":"1", "StudentName":"Rahul", "StudentMarks":"83" }, { "StudentId":"2",   "StudentName":"Rohit",  "StudentMarks":"91"} ]
```

My current code for generate JSON API is like below.

```html
<?php
$response = array();
require 'db.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM news order by id desc";
 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        
    $response["news"] = array();
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             
            $news= array();
            $news["id"] = $row["id"]; 
            $news["title"] = $row["title"];       
            $news["description"] = $row["description"];                
            
          array_push($response["news"], $news);
          }
           $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I am getting response like below

```html
{"news":[{"id":"1","title":"My first news title here","description":"My first news description will be here"}],"success":1}
```

I have tried lot of changes but not getting proper result like above. I want remove "news" and "success" from my response for make it as required response. What should I change for get response like first located code ?

Thanks

Comment: what about `sucess`  response ?

Comment: @Rishi I have added response that I am getting.

Comment: why this `[{{` ? is it `[{` ? , I can see 3 opening and only 2 closing brackets

Comment: @Rishi Sorry...its by mistake of copy paste

Comment: where is student `name` and `marks`? what is column name inside table ?

Comment: @Rishi its just example...I need response in that format...my string is different and its need only id...title and description as in my code. Thanks

Comment: ok, then you should pass `news` directly.  `echo json_encode($response['news]);`

Comment: @Rishi Thanks...Its working fine as per my requirement !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$response = array();
require 'db.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM news order by id desc";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["news"] = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $arr[]=array('StudentId'=>$row["id"],'title'=>$row["title"],'description'=>$row["description"])
          }
           $response =$arr ;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response = array('success'=>0);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```